# Redirection old site with get variables

Tags: .htaccess

In htaccess file, i need to redirect all old site urls to a new one.

My actual redirection recup just the page url in a get variable (source)
I need to add a second variable (hotel) to recup it if it exists.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/page/?source=$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/page/?source=$1 [R=permanent,QSA,L]
```

> **QSA|qsappend** : When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query
>   string, and replace it with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA]
>   flag causes the query strings to be combined.
>   http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

Comment: That doesn't change anything. I have this kind of urls `www.oldsite.com/page/index.html?var=value` i just need to add the var values to the source get variable. The result should be : `www.newsite.com/newpage/?source=page/index.html&var=value`

Comment: That's exactly what `[QSA]` does. Try to clear your cache or with other browser.

Comment: Right, it was a cache problem. It works now. Thank you !